# How to revoke the oauth token in case microsoft api?

Tags: outlook

I need to implement a scenario where person unsubscribes from my app I need to revoke the generated tokens for the person.

Google have this functionality to revoke the tokens but I couldn't find any documentation when it comes to microsoft api's.